# How to stop slide transition into Second VC before it covers UIView?

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, segue, slide

In my application I have a uiview at the top of the screen. When I tap that UIView I have a second View Controller slides up. What I would like to accomplish is that when the second View Controller slides into the screen it stops right before it covers up the UIView

What I am trying to accomplish is have a view slide up that contains store information such as hours open, address, phone number etc. So I was thinking that I could just have another view controller that holds all of this information. Only part is I want to stop it sliding up so it is flush with the uiview bar on top.

```
//tap to bring up the second view controller
@IBAction func showInfoVC(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showSecondVC", sender: self)
}
```

Comment: second controller has no reference to the views in the first controlller. Instead you should try to present a uiview instead of uiview controller, and then you can easily findout if two uiviews are touching or not.

Comment: so are you saying that i should create a custom slide animation for a UIView to slide into the screen? Still relatively new to programming for iOS, any links that you may know of that could direct me to a place where i can learn how to do this?

Comment: I think you have the wrong idea on how to go about doing this. Do you know how to present and dismiss controller modally?

Comment: Most likely I am going about this wrong haha. I do not know how to present and dismiss controller modally. I have been searching online for how to accomplish this task but do not have a clear idea on how to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like your goals are:

1. Have a base View
2. Slide a second View part way up on the first

Assuming this is the case, there are multiple ways you could accomplish this, but Apple would probably recommend [View Controller Containment](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html).  To accomplish this, you will have:

1. A `SlidingContainerViewController`.

   - This is a custom container View Controller that will hold our other two View Controllers
2. Some background View Controller
3. Some foreground View Controller

Here is a basic implementation of a custom SlidingContainerViewController

```
// SlidingContainerViewController.swift

import UIKit

class SlidingContainerViewController: UIViewController {

    //MARK: - Init
    init(frontViewController: UIViewController, backViewController: UIViewController) {
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
        frontViewContoller = frontViewController
        backViewContoller = backViewController
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    //MARK: - Public
    var frontViewContoller: UIViewController = UIViewController()
    var backViewContoller: UIViewController = UIViewController()
    var splitOriginY: CGFloat = 160.0

    func toggleFrontView() {
        if frontIsVisible {
            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.4) {
                self.frontViewContoller.view.frame.origin.y = self.view.frame.height
                self.frontIsVisible = false
            }
        } else {
            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.4) {
                self.frontViewContoller.view.frame.origin.y = self.splitOriginY
                self.frontIsVisible = true
            }

        }
    }

    //MARK: - ViewLifecycle
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        addChild(backViewContoller)
        addChild(frontViewContoller)
        self.frontViewContoller.view.frame.origin.y = self.view.frame.height
    }

    //MARK: - Private
    var frontIsVisible = false

    private func addChild(viewController: UIViewController) {
        addChildViewController(viewController)
        view.addSubview(viewController.view)
        viewController.view.frame = view.bounds
        viewController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
    }

}
```

You can then put any custom View Controllers that you want into this container View Controller.  The bottom View Controller just needs to call `toggleFrontView()` on the container View Controller whenever it wants the slide to occur.

Below I've added two sample View Controllers for demonstrations purposes.
You can view the whole project on github: [SlidingVC](https://github.com/bearMountain/SlidingVC)

[image: SlidingContainerViewController]

*Note: This solution is implemented programmatically without Interface Builder.  I personally build all of my apps completely in code this way.  If you desired to use Interface Builder, you could accomplish the same thing using a Storyboard and custom segues.  Here is a related tutorial: [A Beginner’s Guide to Animated Custom Segues in iOS 8](http://www.appcoda.com/custom-segue-animations/)

Comment: Absolutely Fantastic! Ill try and see if i can properly implement this ASAP! Went through the github and saw you added code to the delegate, as well as I do not see a main storyboard? Still a rookie so i don't completely understand all of it but I will definitely see what i can do :)

Comment: You were able to do this programmatically but i am also wondering if this is just a more advanced way of developing an application or would it be no different if you were to design this in interface builder then code the transitions?  Such implementing the container view in the IB. connecting them via segue, adding a tap gesture recognizer then  add code to allow the view to slide into the screen using performSegueWithIdentifier.

Comment: In my experience, most iOS developers use Interface Builder extensively.  I have used it in the past, but now I do everything completely in code.  For me, I'm a programmer and so it feels more appropriate to do everything in code rather than having some settings hiding in IB and some hiding in code.  I've added a note at the bottom of my answer to address this issue.

Comment: I appreciate it greatly. i am about 6 months into programming, swift, C++, python. C++ and Python from class and swift on my own during school right now. You've provided a lot thank you :)

Comment: Glad it was helpful.  iOS dev rocks, keep with it!  If you every get stuck, feel free to hit me up.  Contact info is on my profile, you can point me to another Stack Overflow post that you make.

Comment: Thank you very much, I wish I would be able to provide you with some value, maybe sometime in the future!