# How to modify slide transition

Tags: swift, animation, uiviewcontroller

I had asked a question similar to this once before but I didn't realize and don't think I can use the same method due to the nuances of the two methods. ([How to stop slide transition into Second VC before it covers UIView?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35301059/5434541))

I ultimately learned how to do the transition using APPCoda's lesson(http://www.appcoda.com/custom-segue-animations/)

The original question resulted in an answer providing a solution using container views and hard coded views. What I am wondering is if I can get the same effect using two separate view controllers and linking them through a segue with a gesture recognizer.

What I would like to accomplish is:

- Have my initial view controller
- Tap Button and have Second View Controller Overlap the first View Controller Partially (By partially I mean I have a UIView on the first View Controller that I want to remain visible. So the top of the second view controller will slide up until it hits the bottom of the UIView).

What I currently have is the original view controller being pushed up and out of the screen by the second view controller sliding up from the bottom of the screen.

Code that handles the transition using a segue from one VC to the sliding VC:

```
import Foundation

class CustomSegueToSecondVC: UIStoryboardSegue
{

override func perform() {
    let originalVC   = self.sourceViewController .view as UIView!
    let slidingVC    = self.destinationViewController.view as UIView!

    let screenWidth  = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width
    let screenHeight = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height

    slidingVC.frame  = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: screenHeight, width: screenWidth, height: screenHeight)

    let window = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow
    window?.insertSubview(slidingVC, aboveSubview: originalVC)

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.4, animations:  { () -> Void in

        originalVC.frame = CGRectOffset(originalVC.frame, 0.0, -screenHeight)
        slidingVC.frame  = CGRectOffset(slidingVC.frame, 0.0, -screenHeight)

        }) { (Finished) -> Void in

            self.sourceViewController.presentViewController(self.destinationViewController as UIViewController, animated: false, completion: nil)

    }
}
};
```

Comment: You can certainly create a transition animation that does what you want. But the way you're doing it is not the way to go. You need to learn how to do custom presentation transition animations properly, using a UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate, UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning, and possibly a custom UIPresentationController subclass. (You can still use a custom segue to embody those things if you want to, but you don't have to.)

Comment: wow, seems like a lot to get a screen to slide up haha. would you say that Appcoda's lesson is the best resource (http://www.appcoda.com/custom-view-controller-transitions-tutorial/) or is there anywhere that you may know of that specifically addresses this issue? @matt

Comment: Example project https://github.com/mattneub/custom-alert-view-iOS7 doesnt slide but it shows how to do partial covering, and it's easy to change the animation so that it slides

Comment: Much appreciated thank you!